# Minha função de fatorial não retorna o valor esperado ! Linguagem C

Tags: c, fatorial

Meu professor está começando a passar funções, e pediu para a gente fazer uma função de fatorial de um número, porém ela sempre retorna o valor errado e eu não sei o que acontece.

Código:

```
int fatorial(int n) {
 int ans = 1;

 while(n>1){
  ans*=n; n--; return ans;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Bom amigo, pelo que eu vi sua função está 90% correta, porém você está retornando o valor **ans** antes que ele esteja completamente correto... Você deve multiplicar todos os números para depois retornar-lo ...

Exemplo:

```
int fatorial(int n) { int ans = 1;

while(n>1){ ans*=n; n--; }
 return ans;
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, mds como sou tonto, obrigado.